# `related_names` not available as a reverse relationship

Tags: django

I have the following models:

> models.py

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    # invoice fields

class LineItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(Invoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lineitems')
    code = models.ForeignKey(Code, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lineitems')
    # other fields
```

I believe I should be able to access related objects of Invoices through `invoice.lineitems.all()` and of Code through `code.lineitems.all()` where `invoice` and `code` are instances of the Model classes.

However, if I do:

```
x = Invoice.objects.last()
x.lineitems.all()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "../.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 816, in __get__
    return self.related_manager_cls(instance)
  File "../.venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 683, in __init__
    super(RelatedManager, self).__init__()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Am I accessing this incorrectly? Perhaps there is a name clash somewhere?

Comment: Perhaps because of your `related_name` has the same value with your model name. Try to rename your model to `LineItem`.

Comment: Sorry looks like it was a typo - the model name is actually `LineItem` in my code

Comment: Your code seems OK. Is it working?